# openssl generate self-signed certificate puts private key and certificate to one file?

Tags: ssl, openssl

for generating self-signed certificate via `openssl` command, usually I specify the `-keyout` and `-out` to different file, but this time I see a command like this, from [python ssl module: Self-signed certificates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#self-signed-certificates)

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout cert.pem
```

It writes the private key to the same file as certificate?
What is advantage of this? why put them together here?

Comment: *"What is advantage of this?"* - Aren't you essentially asking what the advantage is of having only to deal with a single file instead of two files? Isn't it obvious that it makes things simpler? Maybe it gets more clear if you have more than one certificate + key and need to make sure to not mix up certificates with keys.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich No, I mean if the private key is in the certificate, then during TLS handshake the certificate is sent to client right, is this a security issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean if the private key is in the certificate, then during TLS handshake the certificate is sent to client right, is this a security issue?

No. The file does not get send to the peer. The file is used to load the certificate and private key into the application and then only the certificate is send to the peer. There is no difference in this no matter if they are in the same PEM file, in different PEM files, in DER formatted files, in a PKCS#12 file etc - the actual file is never send.